# Can't connect to internet, Ubuntu 16.0.4.1 server

Tags: networking, server

I just installed Ubuntu server using VMware workstation 12 and I'm stuck with setting up my network adapter.

Here are my settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

I attached a NAT network adapter with following settings:

```
subnet ip: 192.168.0.0
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

Network adapter of my host looks like this:

```
ip adress: 192.168.0.2
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
dg: 192.168.0.1
```

On Windows7 which i also installed via VMware, everything works fine.

[image: lscpi output]

Screenshot of my vmware network adapter settings:

[image: VMWare networking settings]

EDIT2:
I statically assigned an IP address to my ubuntu server because I want to create a zimbra mail server and I want to access Ubuntu server from my pc via putty. So, I don't want a dynamic IP address.

Comment: What's your question? What error symptoms do you experience when you try to use the network?

Comment: My ubuntu server doesn't recognize any network adapter when i type ifconfig and i cannot ping for example 8.8.8.8

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Ethernet` (on the guest) and the VMware networking configuration (on the host)? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for new command man :) i'm still learning and any new command is welcome.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nm-tool` (on the guest)? If possible please post command output listings as text and not as image. Thanks.

Comment: nm-tool command not found

Comment: Ok. If you're not using `network-manager` I can't help you unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try changing your guest interface from NAT to Bridged?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work either. It always bringing me same message: network unreachible.

Answer (score 2):

You have statically assigned IP to your guest network which is in the same subnet as your host. Thus you should use bridge mode instead of NAT adapter.

If you don't care about being in the same network as your host, then use DHCP for your guest interface instead of static and stay on NAT adaptor.